# PHP preg match not working

Tags: php, regex

I have a str from witch I want to parse all `<li></li>` tags, this is the string.

```
<li>Want this</li>DON'T WANT THIS<li>Want this</li>DON'T WANT THIS<li>Want this</li>...
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
$my_text= array();
preg_match('/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/', $str, $my_text);
```

But it doesn't work. When I run it this is my_text array:

```
[0] => "<li>Want this</li>"
[1] => "Want this"
```

It only has 2 elements of 1000 of them.

Comment: Have a look at `preg_match_all`

Comment: And also read about `DOMDocument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function, Something like this:

```
<?php

$str = "<li>Want this</li>DON'T WANT THIS<li>Want this</li>DON'T WANT THIS<li>Want this</li>";
preg_match_all('/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/', $str, $out);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/bgdkn)

Answer (score 2):

Toto is correct, it is a really simple fix:

```
$str = "<li>Want this</li>DON'T WANT THIS<li>Want this</li>DON'T WANTTHIS<li>Want this</li>";

$my_text= array();
preg_match_all('/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/', $str, $my_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

May I propose another solution, based on [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) and [xpath queries](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)?

```
<?php
$string = "<html>
            <li>Want this</li>DON'T WANT THIS<li>Want this</li>DON'T WANT THIS<li>Want this</li>
        </html>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
# select only the li elements where the text is equal to...
$elements = $xml->xpath("//li[text() = 'Want this']");
print_r($elements);
// yields a list of your desired elements
?>
```

**Hint:** Your regex works as well, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vR8uQ3/1). Consider using other delimiters though:

```
$regex = '~<li>(.+?)</li>~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match_all, as suggested above. It's really the best solution.

```
preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U", $input, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The above example will remove any html tags from the input, not only li.

Comment: I might need new glasses, but I cannot read anything about *replacing*, am I right?